# Operating homomorphism

Tags: formal-languages, ring-homomorphism

[image: yellow part?]

I'm doing this proof but I'm not sure that the yellow part in the proof is correct. I think it might be true because of the composition between homomorphism, is this correct?

Thank you!

Comment: It's $X^{n+1}=X^nX$

Comment: @M_t_set The claim is correct by virtue of the recursive definition of products over finite families, however there are some errors here and there. The character "h" (as well as "L") isn't used in italics consistently all throughout the text and there is also the relation $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$. By definition $\Sigma^*$ is the free monoid $\mathrm{Mon}(\Sigma)$ on the set $\Sigma$ treated as "the alphabet", and $L$ is meant to be a word in this alphabet, otherwise said an *element* of the free monoid in question. The correct way to express this is $L \in \Sigma^*$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you! I was concerned that for some reason I couldn't do that

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Thank you for the help. As for the italic part I shall correct it, you are right. As for L, I think I understand what you are saying but I think here L isn't a word but a language so L is a set of words that belongs to Sigma* therefore is a subset of sigma*, does this make sense then?

Comment: @M_t_set In this acceptation it does make sense to say $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$, however what then are we to make of $L^n$? What is this notion of exponentiation your are referring to?

Comment: @ΑΘΩ 
L^n=LLL...L n times.
So L^n would be a set of words in which every word is formed with the concatenation of L words n times. So imagine that a is a word in L, a^n is in L^n. Hope I explained it properly

Comment: @M_t_set I see what you mean (i was suspecting it but could not be sure). Please consult the answer below for a bit of general theory.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Pardon me, which answer you talking  about?

Comment: @M_t_set It's in the course of being written as we speak, just a bit of patience...

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Oh I'm sorry! I'm online so my answers are faster than usual.

Comment: @M_t_set No need to apologise. The answer is now ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given arbitrary map $f \colon A \to B$ and subset $X \subseteq A$, we shall use the notation $f[X]=\{f(x)\}_{x \in X}$ to describe the direct image of $X$ through $f$. We introduce the *direct image map* associated to $f$ as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\hat{f} \colon \mathscr{P}(A) &\to \mathscr{P}(B)\\
\hat{f}(X)\colon&=f[X].
\end{align}$$
Consider an arbitrary semigroup $(S, \cdot)$. On the powerset $\mathscr{P}(S)$ consider the binary operation defined by:
$$\begin{align}
\cdot \colon \mathscr{P}(S) \times \mathscr{P}(S) &\to \mathscr{P}(S)\\
\cdot(X, Y)\colon&=XY\colon=\{xy\}_{\substack{x \in X\\y \in Y}}.
\end{align}$$
Equipped with this new operation, $(\mathscr{P}(S), \cdot)$ becomes itself a semigroup, the so-called *extension to the powerset* of the original semigroup structure on $S$. Given an arbitrary subset $X \subseteq S$ and nonzero natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}^{\times}=\mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$, we shall write $X^{(n)}$ for the $n$-th power of element $X$ in the powerset semigroup $\mathscr{P}(S)$.

Consider now a second semigroup $T$ together with a semigroup morphism $f \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Sg}}(S, T)$. The following assertion is immediate:

> **Proposition.** The direct image map $\hat{f} \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Sg}}\left(\mathscr{P}(S), \mathscr{P}(T)\right)$ is a morphism between the powerset semigroups.

*Proof.* Consider arbitrary subsets $X, Y \subseteq S$. We shall establish the relation $f[XY]=f[X]f[Y]$ by double inclusion. Let $w \in f[XY]$ be arbitrary; this means there exists $z \in XY$ such that $w=f(z)$ and by definition of the subset product there exist $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ such that $z=xy$; it follows that $w=f(z)=f(xy)=f(x)f(y) \in f[X]f[Y]$, since obviously $f(x) \in f[X]$ and $f(y) \in f[Y]$. Conversely, let $w \in f[X]f[Y]$; again, by definition of the subset product there exist $u \in f[X]$ and $v \in f[Y]$ such that $w=uv$ and furthermore there exist $x \in X$ such that $u=f(x)$ respectively $y \in Y$ such that $v=f(y)$. We have $w=uv=f(x)f(y)=f(xy) \in f[XY]$, since clearly $xy \in XY$. $\Box$

In general, given a semigroup morphism $g \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Sg}}(P, Q)$ and a *nonempty finite* family $x \in P^I$ (this simply means the index set $I$ is nonempty and finite) such that $(I, T)$ is a totally ordered set (in other words, the object $T$ is a total order on $I$), we have the general relation $g\left(\displaystyle\prod_{\substack{i \in I\\T}}x_i\right)=\displaystyle\prod_{\substack{i \in I\\T}}g(x_i)$. As a particular instance of this, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}^{\times}$ and $x \in P$ we have $g\left(x^n\right)=g(x)^n$.

This applies in your particular instance to the end of deriving the relation $\hat{f}\left(X^{(n)}\right)=\hat{f}(X)^{(n)}$ or more explicitly $f\left[X^{(n)}\right]=f[X]^{(n)}$, for every subset $X \subseteq S$ and every nonzero natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}^{\times}$.

When working with monoids, the above relations are also valid for null exponents, as the powerset semigroup of a monoid $M$ is itself a monoid -- of unity given by $1_{\mathscr{P}(M)}=\left\{1_M\right\}$ -- and in monoids the notion of "product of a finite family" is naturally defined for empty families as well.